# How to obtain the absolute position in .NET MAUI's PanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: .net, maui, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ViewGraphics in my XAML defined like this:

```
 <GraphicsView x:Name="Canvas" Drawable="{StaticResource Renderer}">
     <GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
         <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated" />
     </GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
 </GraphicsView>
```

And the corresponding implementation of `PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated` looks like this:

```
   private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
   {
    Debug.WriteLine($"{e.StatusType} x:= {e.TotalX}|y:= {e.TotalY}");
   }
```

The event only gives me the total changes since beginning but there is no way to access the point TotalX and TotalY are relative to. How can I obtain the position (just like TappedEventArgs provides a .GetPosition method)?

I already asked chatgpt but it stucked since it didnt understand that TotalX and TotalY only give the changes with respect to the point I want to find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the mouse cursor coordinates in .NET Maui on Image click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239189/get-the-mouse-cursor-coordinates-in-net-maui-on-image-click)

Comment: @Shaw Nope, since I aint interested in the Tap event, but PanUpdate event. It's not the same.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Julian I have' implemented a custom polygon drawable and want to track (simple point-polygon-containing-test) whether or not the finger is inside or outside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am guessing you want that x and y when you pan, to get that you can probably calculate it something like this

```
 var x = Math.Max(0, e.TotalX);
 if (x > (Width - Thumb.Width))
 x = (Width - Thumb.Width);
```

This would give you the current y, You would generally do this in the Running state(e.StatusType) otherwise this will always be zero.

You can similarly calculate the y as well